# Linux kernel: define function that inside calls 'jiffies'

Tags: c, kernel

In the Linux kernel, I got definition `tcp_time_stamp_jiffies` that defined just one time at boot:

```
#define tcp_time_stamp_jiffies         ((__u32)(jiffies))
```

But every calling `tcp_time_stamp_jiffies`, in method, loop or event, the values is changing .. , and incremented. Isn't the definition define only 1 with value jiffies which at boot only have 1 value, then that value should be used again and again, not calling jiffies again and again?

trying to add custom module/driver which need value `tcp_time_stamp jiffies` at first boot

```
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>
#include <net/tcp.h>

#define tcp_time_stamp_jiffies          ((__u32)(jiffies))

static ssize_t myread(struct file *file, char __user *ubuf,size_t count, loff_t *ppos) 
{
....
printk(KERN_ALERT "tcp_time_stamp_jiffies value : %u\n", tcp_time_stamp_jiffies);
.....
}
```

expected every function myread is called, it show `tcp_time_stamp_jiffies` value at first time/boot. instead it show incremented number every called which always different.

Answer (score 0):

A macro (`#define`) is a text replacement.

Every time you write `tcp_time_stamp_jiffies` the compiler replaces it with `((__u32)(jiffies))`. It will read the value of `jiffies` every time.